# How to reload KTDatatable with new parameters?

Tags: datatable, datatables, metronic

I am using KtDatatable for my datatable
i have problem when I want to reload my table with  new parameters.
Usually in regular datatable we used this

```
'data': function(d) {
     d.date_range = getDaterange();
     d.payment_status = getPaymentStatus();
 }
```

but in KTDatatable I cant used that, so i used this

```
params: {
           query: {
                  generalSearch: 'tes',
                  date_range: getDaterange()

           },
         },
```

The problem is when I call

```
datatable.reload()
```

in KTDatatable, it wont get my new parameters with getDaterange() function

I also use this like in regular datatable

```
datatable.api().ajax.reload();
```

But it show error .api is not function.
How can i send new parameters to my api when reload the datatable ?
Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
params: {
       query: {
              generalSearch: 'tes',
              date_range: getDaterange()

       },
     }
```

this will only send the initial value of getDaterange()

try this code

```
params: {
       query: {
              generalSearch: 'tes',
              date_range: function(){
                 return getDaterange();
              }

       },
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is more than 1 year old but here is the solution that worked for me today November 9, 2021:

It worked for me to destroy the table and then re-initialize it sending the new data so first I do this:

```
$('#kt_datatatable').KTDatatatable('destroy');
```

Then I start the table

```
KTDatatableChildDataLocalDemo.init(jsonData);
```

You could also try to reload the table:

```
$('#kt_datatatable').KTDatatatable('reload');
```

Answer (score 0):

datatable.search("value colum", 'name colum');

or if you want to see the applicable functions and objects
console.log(datatable);

Answer (score 0):

try this function
datatable.setDataSourceParam(param, value)

https://keenthemes.com/metronic/?page=docs&section=html/components/datatable